# Should we delete questions posted during the private beta?

Tags: support, private-beta

I have seen that there are a lot of questions posted during the private beta that have delete votes.

The non-binding vote-to-delete is a privilege granted to:

- [Access to Moderator tools](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). As of September 10, 2023, only 16 users have this privilege. These users can vote-to-delete closed questions.
- [Trusted Users (+20k)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). As of September 10, 2023, only five users have this privilege. These users can vote-to-delete questions having a score of -3 and lower and closed questions.

Most of the users having a non-binding vote-to-delete privilege haven't actively participated during 2023, some since ever a longer time.

Should the questions posted during the private beta having votes-to-delete be deleted?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Questions posted during the private beta had the purpose to help shape the site scope. Many of them have linked from this site or from Meta SE discussing the scope of this site. Considering this it might not be a good idea to delete them.

Only questions that blatantly ignored the private beta purpose and those that are causing harm to the community should be deleted.

One way that a post cause harm to the community is by attracting too many users that doesn't behave according to the code of conduct, like spammers or users that continually use the site to have large discussions that doesn't help the community to grow and improve.

Instead of deleting them lets close them. If they atract edits, answers or comments only affecting a specific the posts of a specific question, that question might be locked using the historical lock. If you find a question in this situation flag it to moderator attention clearly explaining why do you think that should be locked.

## Related

### From this site

- [How generic is too generic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22/88163)
- [Questions' Titles that hit #1 rank in Google Search](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/79/88163)
- [When should I vote to delete a question on Web Applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4463/88163)
- [Overzealous app recommendation closing/deleting](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4491/88163)

### From Meta Stack Exchange

- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/289691)
- [What is "private beta" status?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63401/289691)

Answer (score 7):

They should be judged individually based on current standards. The fact that they were asked during private beta is irrelevant, really.